Show that the system $\dot{x}=-x-y+x\left(x^2+2 y^2\right), \dot{y}=x-y+y\left(x^2+2 y^2\right)$ has at least one periodic solution.
Show that the system $\dot{x}=-x-y+x\left(x^2+2 y^2\right), \dot{y}=x-y+y\left(x^2+2 y^2\right)$ has at least one periodic solution.
My solution is as follows,
\begin{align}
    r\dot{r} &= x\dot{x} + y\dot{y}\\
    &= x(-x-y+x\left(x^2+2 y^2\right)) + y(x-y+y\left(x^2+2 y^2\right))\\
    &= -x^2 - y^2 + (x^2 + y^2)(x^2 + 2y^2)\\
    &=(x^2 + y^2)(x^2 + 2y^2 - 1)\\
    &= r^2(r^2 + r^2\sin^2\theta - 1)\\
  \dot{r}  &= r(r^2 + r^2\sin^2\theta - 1)
\end{align}
We have
$$r^2 \leq r^2 + r^2\sin^2\theta  \leq 2r^2$$
When $r < \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ we have $\dot{r} < 0$, and therefore we can set our trapping region to be the circle of raidus $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ centered at the origin. However, the origin is a fixed point but we will be done if we can show that this point is unstable. The jacobian of this system is
$$J = \begin{bmatrix}
-1 + 3x^2 & -1 + 4xy\\
1 + 2xy & -1 + x^2 + 6y^2
\end{bmatrix}$$
$$J(0, 0) = \begin{bmatrix}
-1 & -1 \\
1 & -1
\end{bmatrix}$$
which has eigenvalues
$(-1 - \lambda)^2 + 1 = 0 \implies \lambda = -1 \pm i$. However, this shows that the origin is stable...

Your derived inequality suggests to consider the region $\frac12\le r^2\le 1$. You could also restore your standard situation if you reverse the time direction.

on the boundary $r^2 = 1/2$ the $\dot{r} < 0$ while when $r = 1$, $\dot{r} > 0$. Shouldn't the inequalities be reversed if we want this annulus to be our trapping region.

That's why the reversal of the time arrow. Sometimes it is not where the solution goes to but where it came from. You get an unstable closed orbit.

Ahh I see. Would the region that you stated be a trapping region if we look at it backwards in time? On the other hand would the origin also be unstable if we look at it backwards in time. I guess I only need one of these to conclude that I have a closed orbit.

Yes, and yes if you do not want to make full use of all available information,

The system would be periodic if the eigenvalues of the Jacobian were purely imaginary, but this is not the case.
This is because the solution to this system is $x(t) = e^{Jt}x(0)$. The system is periodic iff
$x(t) = x(t+T)$  for  some $T$. This implies $e^{JT} = I$, which means $e^{\lambda_iT} = 1$, or $\lambda_i = 2k \pi j /T$.
There is also no other equilibrium point besides $(0, 0)$. So how will this system be periodic?
